# Call JSP function with JSoup

Tags: java, jsp, jsoup

I'm trying to **scrape** a .jsp webpage with Jsoup. The page I'm trying to **scrape** is basically a 6 steps form, filling each form takes me to another one but to do so I must click a button that calls a jsp function. I don't know how to do so with jsoup.

So here is a piece of the jsp page I'm trying to **scrape**.

```
<img id="nextButtonId" onkeypress="disableButtons(this);onIntroductionFormSubmit()" height="50" 
 alt="suivant" title="suivant" src="/eAppointment54-etrangers/element/images/buttons/next.gif" 
 **onclick="disableButtons(this);onIntroductionFormSubmit()"** onmouseover="downNextSrcPicture(this);" 
 onmouseout="upNextSrcPicture(this);" style="display: block;">
```

I want to call the onclick methods onclick="disableButtons(this);onIntroductionFormSubmit(). Maybe there is a way I can do this without having to simulate the actual clicking.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jsoup is not a browser engine, it is just an HTML parser/writer. To do such a thing you should do one of these, I recommend the first one:

- Implement the method yourself (it's probably just an HTTP call)
- Use an automation library like Selenium (no experience)
- (Not recommended) Run a full browser environment such as JavaFX WebView and inject code to do the action.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that